# Formatting and organizing the Spreadsheet result

Tags: xml, excel, xslt

I am trying to create a Excel file with the following code

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Document>
  <Header>
    <NoInvoices>3</NoInvoices>
    <ExportDate>11-20-2015</ExportDate>
  </Header>
  <Invoices>
    <Type>CN</Type>
    <Customer>Juan</Customer>
    <CustAddress>New Bilibid</CustAddress>
    <InvNumber>01234</InvNumber>
    <Items>
      <Name>Sugar</Name>
      <Qty>2</Qty>
      <Price>5</Price>
      <Amount>10</Amount>
      <OrigInv>01235</OrigInv>
    </Items>
  </Invoices>
  <Invoices>
    <Type>SI</Type>
    <Customer>Juan</Customer>
    <CustAddress>New Bilibid</CustAddress>
    <InvNumber>01235</InvNumber>
    <Items>
      <Name>Coffee</Name>
      <Qty>5</Qty>
      <Price>25</Price>
      <Amount>125</Amount>
    </Items>
    <Items>
      <Name>Sugar</Name>
      <Qty>5</Qty>
      <Price>5</Price>
      <Amount>25</Amount>
    </Items>
  </Invoices>
  <Invoices>
    <Type>SI</Type>
    <Customer>Julianna</Customer>
    <CustAddress>New Wares</CustAddress>
    <InvNumber>01236</InvNumber>
    <Items>
      <Name>Margarine</Name>
      <Qty>1</Qty>
      <Price>50</Price>
      <Amount>50</Amount>
    </Items>
    <Items>
      <Name>Butter</Name>
      <Qty>10</Qty>
      <Price>10</Price>
      <Amount>100</Amount>
    </Items>
  </Invoices>
</Document>
```

I have this XSLT code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
 xmlns:user="urn:my-scripts"
 xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
 xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
 xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:rs="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset"
 xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema">

  <xsl:output method="xml" media-type="application/vnd.ms-excel" encoding="ISO-8859-1" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
      xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
      xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
      xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
      xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"
      encoding="ISO-8859-1">
      <xsl:call-template name="Styles"></xsl:call-template>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Document" />

    </Workbook>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name ="Styles">
    <Styles >
      <Style ss:ID="Default" ss:Name="Normal">
        <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
        <Borders/>
        <Font/>
        <Interior/>
        <NumberFormat/>
        <Protection/>
      </Style>
      <Style ss:ID="s1">
        <Alignment ss:Vertical="Center" ss:Horizontal="Center" ss:WrapText="1"/>
        <Borders>
          <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
           ss:Color="#000000"/>
          <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
           ss:Color="#000000"/>
          <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
           ss:Color="#000000"/>
        </Borders>
        <Interior ss:Color="#FFB42A" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
        <Font x:Family="Swiss" ss:Bold="1" />
      </Style>
    </Styles>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Document">
    <Worksheet>
      <xsl:attribute name="ss:Name">Invoices</xsl:attribute>
      <Table x:FullColumns="1" x:FullRows="1">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Invoices" />
      </Table>
    </Worksheet>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Items">
    <Cell>
      <Data ss:Type="String">
        <xsl:value-of select ="Name"/>
      </Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell>
      <Data ss:Type="Number">
        <xsl:value-of select ="Qty"/>
      </Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell>
      <Data ss:Type="Number">
        <xsl:value-of select ="Price"/>
      </Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell>
      <Data ss:Type="Number">
        <xsl:value-of select ="Amount"/>
      </Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell>
      <Data ss:Type="String">
        <xsl:value-of select ="OrigInv"/>
      </Data>
    </Cell>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Invoices">
    <Row>
      <Cell>
        <Data ss:Type="String">
          <xsl:value-of select ="InvNumber"/>
        </Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell>
        <Data ss:Type="String">
          <xsl:value-of select ="Type"/>
        </Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell>
        <Data ss:Type="String">
          <xsl:value-of select ="Customer"/>
        </Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell>
        <Data ss:Type="String">
          <xsl:value-of select ="CustAddress"/>
        </Data>
      </Cell>
      <xsl:apply-templates select ="Items" />
    </Row>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which results to this, and also what I need

[image]

Can anyone help me to arrange my code so that It will be like in the picture.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to approach generating Excel XML, is to make the changes you want in Excel, save it, and then look at the XML that is generated. Often the changes needed in XSLT won't actually be that difficult once you know what to aim for.

At the moment you are doing one row per `Invoice` item in your XML, when really you want one row per `Items` element. However, some consideration needs to be given to the rendering of the rows to get the intended output, as the first row for each invoice will have different formatting to the other rows for an invoice

1. The first four cells for the first `Items` for each `Invoice` will need a `ss:MergeDown` attribute, so that the fields for the invoice span down to cover all item rows.
2. For the other `Items` for each `Invoice` they will need to start at the 5th column, and so an `ss:cellIndex` will be needed to specify the start column

Try this XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
 xmlns:user="urn:my-scripts"
 xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
 xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
 xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:rs="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset"
 xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema">

  <xsl:output method="xml" media-type="application/vnd.ms-excel" encoding="ISO-8859-1" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
      xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
      xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
      xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
      xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"
      encoding="ISO-8859-1">
      <xsl:call-template name="Styles"></xsl:call-template>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Document" />

    </Workbook>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name ="Styles">
    <Styles >
      <Style ss:ID="Default" ss:Name="Normal">
        <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
        <Borders/>
        <Font/>
        <Interior/>
        <NumberFormat/>
        <Protection/>
      </Style>
      <Style ss:ID="s1">
        <Alignment ss:Vertical="Center" ss:Horizontal="Center" ss:WrapText="1"/>
        <Borders>
          <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
           ss:Color="#000000"/>
          <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
           ss:Color="#000000"/>
          <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"
           ss:Color="#000000"/>
        </Borders>
        <Interior ss:Color="#FFB42A" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
        <Font x:Family="Swiss" ss:Bold="1" />
      </Style>
    </Styles>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Document">
    <Worksheet>
      <xsl:attribute name="ss:Name">Invoices</xsl:attribute>
      <Table x:FullColumns="1" x:FullRows="1">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Invoices" />
      </Table>
    </Worksheet>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Items">
    <xsl:param name="cellIndex" select="1"></xsl:param>
    <Cell>
      <xsl:if test="$cellIndex > 1">
          <xsl:attribute name="ss:Index">
              <xsl:value-of select="$cellIndex" />
          </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:if>
      <Data ss:Type="String">
        <xsl:value-of select ="Name"/>
      </Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell>
      <Data ss:Type="Number">
        <xsl:value-of select ="Qty"/>
      </Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell>
      <Data ss:Type="Number">
        <xsl:value-of select ="Price"/>
      </Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell>
      <Data ss:Type="Number">
        <xsl:value-of select ="Amount"/>
      </Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell>
      <Data ss:Type="String">
        <xsl:value-of select ="OrigInv"/>
      </Data>
    </Cell>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Invoices">
    <xsl:variable name="merge" select="count(Items) - 1" />
    <Row>
      <Cell ss:MergeDown="{$merge}">
        <Data ss:Type="String">
          <xsl:value-of select ="InvNumber"/>
        </Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell ss:MergeDown="{$merge}">
        <Data ss:Type="String">
          <xsl:value-of select ="Type"/>
        </Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell ss:MergeDown="{$merge}">
        <Data ss:Type="String">
          <xsl:value-of select ="Customer"/>
        </Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell ss:MergeDown="{$merge}">
        <Data ss:Type="String">
          <xsl:value-of select ="CustAddress"/>
        </Data>
      </Cell>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Items[1]" />
    </Row>
    <xsl:for-each select="Items[position() > 1]">
        <Row>
            <xsl:apply-templates select=".">
                <xsl:with-param name="cellIndex" select="5" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </Row>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi nice solution, but I have a question, will the code below handle Items more than 2 or not <xsl:if test="Items[2]">
        <Row>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Items[position() > 1]">
                <xsl:with-param name="cellIndex" select="5" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </Row>
    </xsl:if>,  because usually invoices are more than 2 items

Comment: Yes, it will handle more than two. That "if" statement is just testing if there is a second item, and if it there is it then applies the template for all other items, not just the second. If there are three items, for example, the if still returns true, and all is good.

Comment: Ah ok, because I tried it, and on the third, the <Row> is not being triggered, and results to an error, can you try on your side to add one more Items, thanks for the help

Comment: My apologies, I now see my mistake. It was not creating separate `row` elements for subsequent items. I've updated my answer, which also removes the need for the `xsl:if` too.